# Factorizing a quartic expression to show that it is a perfect square.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quartics, multivariate-polynomial

> Show that $\frac{a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4}{2}$ is a perfect square.

I tried this,
$$\frac{a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4}{2}$$
$$\frac{a^4+b^4+(a^2+b^2+2ab)^2}{2}$$
$$\frac{2a^4+2b^4+4a^2b^2+2(a^2b^2+2a^3b+2ab^3)}{2}$$
$$a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2+ab(ab+2a^2+2b^2)$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+ab(ab+2a^2+2b^2)$$

What can I do next?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1983377/42969

Comment: What is $a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4$?

Comment: Or simply ask Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+%28a%5E4%2B+b%5E4+%2B+%28a%2Bb%29%5E4%29%2F2

Comment: Please use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) to search if your question exists here before asking.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for the link to "Approach Zero". A very useful search engine indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4$ is a square, it has to be of the form $(xa^2+yab+zb^2)^2$ for some coefficients $x,y,z$.

Then $a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4=x^2a^4+2xya^3b+(y^2+2xz)a^2b^2+2yzab^3+z^2b^4$.

Comparing coefficients we get $x^2=1, 2xy=2, y^2+2xz=3,2yz=2,z^2=1$.

Solving this system we get $x=y=z=1$ and $x=y=z=-1$, so $a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4=(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$